# Log4j2.xml :Stop InactivityMonitor from populating console

Tags: logging, log4j2

I have recently changed the logging from logback to log4j2.xml both implementation and API. I can see  InactivityMonitor is population console 100/per sec and it's disturbing. Can anyone please guide me to stop it from spamming the console? 
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW66R.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="INFO">
       <Appenders>
          <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
             <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %X{userId} [%thread] %logger:%line - %msg %n" />
             <Filters>
                 <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
             </Filters>
          </Console>
          <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/pir.log" filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/pir.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
             <BurstFilter level="INFO" />
             <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %X{userId} [%thread] %logger:%line - %msg %n</Pattern>
             </PatternLayout>
             <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB" />
             </Policies>
             <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
          </RollingFile>

       </Appenders>
       <Loggers>
          <Logger name="simflex.pir" level="debug" additivity="false">
             <AppenderRef ref="file" />
             <AppenderRef ref="console" />
          </Logger>
          <Root level="error">
             <AppenderRef ref="console"  level="error"/>
             <AppenderRef ref="file" />

          </Root>
       </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add your configuration file settings to your post?

Answer (score 0):

The messages in your link are coming from ActiveMQ. This [FAQ](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging) from ActiveMQ indicates that it is using Log4j 1.x for its logging. To migrate it to Log4j 2 you need to remove the log4j 1.x jar from your application and replace it with the log4j-1.2-api jar from Log4j 2.

Comment: It's not working. this is my pom.xml                                                                                                                                           
             <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> –

Comment: You have two options. Option 1. run mvn dependency:tree and see what is bringing in log4j1. Option 2. Look in lib directory (or whatever directory contains all the jars) and manually remove the log4j 1 jar.